# print only numbers on selenium "find_element"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to do something really useful to me, but i have a problem.

this is the code line that give-me the result "5,0 km"

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


#C:\Users\jefferson\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers


servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
navegador.get("https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir//")


#digitar primeiro endereço

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys("Rimatur Transportes, Rodovia Curitiba - Ponta Grossa Br-277, Km 2,1875 - Mossunguê, Curitiba - PR, 82305-100")

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc50"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#destino

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys("Av. Juscelino Kubitschek De Oliveira - Ld, 2600 - Cidade Industrial De Curitiba, Curitiba - PR, 81260-900")

navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_ifc51"]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


#def directions():
#    sleep(10)
#    directions = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/button")
#    directions.click()
#directions()

def km():
    sleep(10)
    kmtotal=navegador.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
    txt = kmtotal.text
    value = float(txt)
    print(value)
km()
```

I want to print only the "5,0" without KM to mount routes, how can i modify my code to print / save it in a variable?

thanks <3

a lot of things :(

PRINT ONLY NUMBER AND COMMA

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def km():
    sleep(10)
    kmtotal=navegador.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div')
    txt = kmtotal.text #extract the entire text content from the web element
    value = float(txt)  # extract the float from the string
    print(value) # print it
km()
```

Comment: i got this error now >   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5,0 km'

i will edit my post and put the full code

Comment: Probably will be better if you open a new question for that so that it will appear on the top of the feed

Comment: i solve this problem bro, but i got another one hahahahha

    km1 = kmtotal.text
    value = km1.replace('km', '')
    kmprint = value
    a = 5
    print(kmprint + a)

i can't multiply the result 5,0 by anyway :(

Comment: Check if after ` km1.replace('km', '')` the `value` doesn't contain spaces etc. also you probably will need to extract the number value from the string. String is a text. It's not a number